# Julia syntax - Return type annotation for a function with a where clause

Tags: julia

I'm new to Julia. This may be a stupid question, but I can't seem to get the syntax for this right.

I can do

```
check_condition(func::F, arg::Int) where {F} = func(arg)
```

and

```
check_condition(func::Function, arg::Int)::Bool = func(arg)
```

But if I want to include both the type annotation and the external where clause I keep getting syntax errors. The following don't seem to work:

```
check_condition(func::F, arg::Int) where {F}::Bool = func(arg)
(check_condition(func::F, arg::Int) where {F})::Bool = func(arg)
check_condition(func::F, arg::Int)::Bool where {F} = func(arg)
check_condition::Bool(func::F, arg::Int) where {F} = func(arg)
```

This does work, but I believe it is not equivalent to what I want, since the type parameter is hidden from the method body (assume I want to use it somewhere within)

```
check_condition(func::F where {F}, arg::Int)::Bool = func(arg)
```

What is the proper way of writing this?

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

use:

```
(check_condition(func::F, arg::Int)::Bool) where {F} = ...
```

Note that `::Bool` does conversion to `Bool`. E.g.:

```
julia> (check_condition(func::F, arg::Int)::Bool) where {F}= 1
check_condition (generic function with 1 method)

julia> check_condition(5,7)
true
```

Comment: In this case the curly brace can be omitted so ` (check_condition2(func::F, arg::Int)::Bool) where F = 1` will work as well